# I get this django error 421, b'service not available (connection refused, too many connections when signing up for my account, i dont really know?

Tags: django, email, gmail

SMTPConnectError at /investor/signup
(421, b'service not available (connection refused, too many connections)')

This Error has been delaying for days now, i'm really stuck while sending email with django and i'm a beginner in django that why i do not have many idea on how to solve this issue please can anyone help?

**Setting.py**

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, isn't it? The receiving mail server blocks you because you opened too many connections, maybe in the last days or hours. (This is up to the server admin.)

Comment: @robert Okay so please what do I do now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Fix this issue, the easiest way to is use to [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) as thier server doesn't throw all the regular error gmail Simple Mail Transfer Protocol Throws. To get started using SendGrid in django, this is the best tutorial [Article 1](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/django) and [Official SendGrid X Django Docs](https://www.twilio.com/blog/using-twilio-sendgrid-send-emails-python-django)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've found the solution to this bug but coincidentally, I encountered the same issue recently... Here is the solution that worked for me. My assumption is that you already know how to generate secret password from gmail smpt.

I tried this using the EmailMessage class and the send_mail function. Both worked perfectly.

I'll share portions of both my settings.py and views.py files.Hope it works for you too... cheers!

```
                    settings.py    
# smtp configuration    
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'    
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'    
EMAIL_PORT = 587    
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'    
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'    
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True                         
                           
                   views.py
# user activation     

current_site = get_current_site(request)
email_subject = 'Please activate your account',    
message = render_to_string('accounts/account_verification_email.html', {
   'user': user,
   'domain': current_site,
   'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
   'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user)    
})    
from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER    
recipient = [email]    
send_email = EmailMessage( email_subject, message, from_email, recipient)    
send_email.send(fail_silently=False)
```

#### **Alternate method using send_mail function:**

```
subject = 'This is a mail from IfeCog'
message = f'hi {firstname}, this mail is about your registration'
from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER 
recipient_list = [email]  
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: thanks for your ans. i haven't solved it yet but i'll try your solution

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried enabling 'Less secure app access' , go to your gmail host 'manage account' -> 'security', make sure you have 'Less secure app access' enabled.

Comment: No I haven't, let me try it
Thanks Alot for trying to help me ❤️

Comment: Hello @DestinyFranks I will suggest you to use third party services like sendgrid to send email check this doc to send email using sendgrid in django https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/django

Comment: Okay thanks alot, let me try it now

Answer (score 0):

To Fix this is very challenging, but the answer is quite simple:
First change
`EMAIL_USE_TLS = False`, then set `EMAIL_USE_SSL = True`, and finally change the port number to `465`.